# How do i properly set my JAVA HOME environment variable for Spring Tool Suite?

Tags: java

I keep getting the following error message when opening `Spring Tool Suite` with a `Roo` project open.

With previous projects i did not have this problem. So, it might have something to do with `Roo`?

> Message: Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git user global
>   configuration and to define the default location to store
>   repositories: 'C:\Users\Media Markt Apeldoor'. If this is not correct
>   please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse.
>   Otherwise Git for Windows and EGit might behave differently since they
>   see different configuration options. This warning can be switched off
>   on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

But my environment variable(both User and System) is set as follows, pointing to my JDK directory:

Variable name: `JAVA_HOME`
Variable value: `C:\Program~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_91`

and my JDK is here:
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91`

So, the "~1" should be fine in the value of the variable.

For setting the environment variable i followed this site to the letter:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html

I have added this info to my question:
When i look into the session data of this program Spring Tool Suite i see the following which confuses me know since i have a 64 bit -system.eclipse.buildId=3.8.0.201606301029-RELEASE-e46

java.version=1.8.0_91

java.vendor=Oracle Corporation

BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US

Framework arguments:  -product org.springsource.sts.ide

Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.springsource.sts.ide

Comment: What OS are you using? Windows? HOME and JAVA_HOME are completely different variables. I guess JAVA_HOME, as you told, is set correctly. HOME should point to something like `C:\Users\Arend`

Comment: That BootLoader constant info i added above in the question sounds strange to me since i have a 64 bit system: BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution in my case:

Variable name: JAVA_HOME

Variable value: C:\Program~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin

Variable name: HOME

Variable value: %USERPROFILE%

No more errors

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by just changing the name to "HOME" instead of "JAVA_HOME"

Variable name: HOME Variable value: C:\Program~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_91

Thank you Ulrich for helping out.

Comment: I'm really surprised... I think that HOME should point to your home directory and definitely NOT to the installation folder of Java

Comment: You are correct. So I made two entries, one for HOME and one for JAVA-HOME. Just learning, :-)

Comment: perhaps you'd like to update your answer to be more clear that you've added in the HOME and kept the JAVA-HOME?  and to accept the answer while you're at it.